# Footer layout appears above keypad

Tags: android, android-webview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".feature.webview.WebViewActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_14"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_14">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/defaultContentDescription"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_14"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_back"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/defaultContentDescription"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_hundred_for_good" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/defaultContentDescription"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_profile"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_14"
        android:background="@color/white">

    </View>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_60"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_60"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/defaultContentDescription"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_home" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.20"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_record_act"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_3">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_record_act"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/defaultContentDescription"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_setting" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.20"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:text="@string/record_act"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/defaultContentDescription"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_dashboard" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.20"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_3"
                android:text="@string/dashboard"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_10" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My layout has a webview and a footer layout at the bottom.

While entering text in any fields inside webview, the footer layout displays on top on keypad. I tried setting **android:windowSoftInputMode="somevalue"** in manifest file. I removed the **android:layout_weight** parameter and hardcoded the height. In both cases it works fine and footer does not appear over keypad, but causes another issue, that is , the keypad now overlaps on edit fields of webview. Before applying those fixes, the fields scrolled up automatically when keypad becomes visible.

How to make sure that the footer layout remains at the bottom and edit fields to scroll up whenever the keypad shows up?

Comment: send the full code of your xml

Comment: Updated the full xml code. @007

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_footer" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_record_act"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this will be the code you have to write in your activcity

```
relativeLayoutScreen.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int heightDiff = relativeLayoutScreen.getRootView().getHeight() - relativeLayoutScreen.getHeight();

                    if (heightDiff > 100) {
                        Log.e("MyActivity", "keyboard opened");
                        relativeLayoutFooter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("MyActivity", "keyboard closed");
                        relativeLayoutFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
```

**I think this will work.**
In this relativeLayoutScreen is the parent main layout.
and and relativeLayoutFooter is the footer layout name

This is tested code and working..

Comment: Tried, but did not work. The footer still appears over keypad

Comment: If I add "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"" in the manifest, it works but as I said, auto scroll of edit fields stops and keypad overlaps on edit fields.

Comment: please check the answer this is working fine now @abhishekmaharajpet

Comment: Thanks, this works!! But I feel this is more of a hack. Multiple times callback is thrown in "onGlobalLayout()". I have seen some flickering issue too. I will stick to this solution for now. I will keep digging if this can be fixed just by changing layout structure and manifest attributes. Thanks once again.